# Unable to write log to file in Spring boot application

Tags: java, spring-boot, logback

In logback-spring.xml i have defined appender below

```
<appender name="rollingFileAppender" class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender">
  <rollingPolicy class="ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.TimeBasedRollingPolicy">
    <FileNamePattern>C:/logs/service.%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log</FileNamePattern>
    <MaxHistory>30</MaxHistory>
  </rollingPolicy>
  <encoder>
    <pattern>%d %-5level [%thread] %logger{0}: %msg%n</pattern>
  </encoder>
</appender>
```

But it is not generating log file at C:/logs/

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58565070/how-to-generalize-logback-files-paths-to-both-windows-linux-os it uses double slashes after the drive name

Comment: I think you should add debug level. like this
  ```
 <root level="debug">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
    </root>
```